# How to properly perform LINQ joins

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am currently developing my first database driven, .NET MVC application and in it I have a table called Animals that contains a number of fields. One field is the breed of the animal, in this field I am holding an Id to another Breed table where the text for the breed is actually stored.

Using LINQ, how to I join the tables and then send the data to the view so it can be viewed in a tabled format like so
:[image]

In the image where the Breed column is displaying a list of numbers, I want it to be the actual bred related to that in the Breed table

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes Kirill, I used DB first approach

Comment: So Linq queries can have a [join clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx). Try that and see if it works. FYI Linq is nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: You're showing the outside. We're more interested in the inside, like a class diagram.

Comment: If this is EF, than you should use navigation properties instead of external Join. Set Foreign Key from one table to another and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

use Navigation Properties, which you can generate from your model.

Then your class should look like that.

```
public class Animals {
  //primitive properties
  public int Id {get;set;}
  //etc.

  //Navigation Properties
  public virtual Breeds Breeds {get;set;}
}

public class Breeds {
  //prmitive properties
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

  //Navigation properties
  public virtual ICollection<Animals> Animals {get;set;}
}
```

then to get an entity with a navigation property :

```
var animal = Repository.Animals.Include(m => m.Breed)
                       .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == <someId>);
```

and you can use (imagine the model of your view is an `Animals`)

```
@Html.Displayfor(m => m.Breed.Name)
```